# Предлог "при" и его правильное употребление

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

В Интернете часто встречаются подобные предложения:

> При заболеваниях поджелудочной железы из рациона исключают сладкое.
>   Что стоит делать при боли?

Корректен ли такой подход? Чем можно заменить?

Answer (score 2):

Такой подход корректен, он соответствует одному из словарных значений предлога ПРИ.

> ПРИ, предлог .... Указывает на свойства, качества и т.п., являющиеся причиной чего-л.; с. При его уме и образованности можно получить хорошее место. При таком больном сердце легко уйти из жизни. При такой силе ума не надо. * Что ежели, сестрица, При красоте такой и петь ты мастерица? (Крылов) ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8))

Чем можно заменить? В каждом конкретом случае это решается по-разному. Но всякая замена меняет стилевую или смысловую окраску.